# What is the type of the callback function in filter of Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
ordersData = [
  { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
  { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
  { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
  { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
  ];
  

constructor( private objHelloService: HelloServiceService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) 
  {  
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: new FormArray([])
      });
       
      this.addCheckboxes();
  }

  private addCheckboxes() 
  {
    this.ordersData.forEach((o, i) => {
                                        const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
                                        (this.form.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control);
                                      });
  }
  

submit() 
    {
      const selectedOrderIds = this.form.value.orders.map((v:string, i:number) => v ? this.form.value.orders[i].id : null).filter(v => v !== null);
      console.log(selectedOrderIds);
    }
```

Problem is here:

```
.filter(v => v !== null)
```

Typescript is saying that I have not specified the type of `v`.
What would be the type of `v` here?
How to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the `orderData` **schema** it would be like this

```
{id: number, name: string}
```

but after you map it to an array of `ID`so your **schema** would be like this

```
.filter((v: number) => v !== null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below,

```
const selectedOrderIds = this.form.value.orders
                               .filter(i => i !== null)  //Filter array of orders by null check
                               .map(v => v.id)  //Get only ids out of array of orders
```

```js
ordersData = [
  { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
  null,
  { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
  null,
  { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
  null,
  { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
  ];
  
const selectedOrderIds = ordersData
                      .filter(i => i !== null) //Filter array of orders by null check
                      .map(v => v.id)  //Get only ids out of array of orders
  
  
console.log(selectedOrderIds)  //[100, 200, 300, 400]
```

Comment: Where have you specified the type of the callback function?

Comment: I have not specified any type of the callback functions. I changed sequence of `map()` and `filter()` where filter returns specific type of filtered array

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped. Please explain what was I doing and what are you doing and how is it all different. I am new to all this.

Comment: I described purpose of `.filter()` and `.map()` in the comment section. You were projecting new array of ids and then you were doing null check. This is why you were getting issues of type. It would be great if you read documentation of [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Correct way is to filter out array of not null elements and get ids out of it.. That is what I did in my answer

Comment: I am glad my comment satisfied your query. I would highly recommend you to go through official documentation which I mentioned in my comment

Comment: I will, surely.